# Restriction on duplicate entry with respect to another column entry

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, criteria

I have two models `Member` and `Saving` with

```
Member('id','name')
Saving('id','member_id','amount','month')
```

I have to restrict duplicate entry of saving of a member for a given month.

**Member.php**

```
class Member extends Model
{
protected $fillable=['name','address','phone']; 
public function loan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Loan::class,'member_id','id');
}
public  function savings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Saving::class,'member_id','id');
}
}
```

**Saving.php**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Saving extends Model
{
protected $fillable=['amount','month','member_id']; 
 public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member','member_id','id');
} 
}
```

Is it possible to implement restriction, using functions in model, or controller?
EDIT:
this is how i tried.
**SavingController.php**

```
    public function addSaving(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('get')){
        $memberData = Member::all();
        return view($this->_pagePath.'saving.addsaving',compact('memberData')); 
        //return redirect()->back();
    }
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'amount' => 'required',
            'month' => 'required'
        ]);
        $data['amount'] = $request->amount;
        $data['month'] = $request->month;
        $data['member_id']= $request->name;
        $member= Member::find(1);
        if($member->savings()->where('month',$request->month)->exists())
        {
          return 'Savings for this month are already added.';
        }
        else
        {
        if(DB::table('savings')->insert($data)){
            return redirect()->route('saving')->with('success','data was successfuly inserted');
        }
    }
                }
 }
```

Comment: What is the type of your `month` field? Is it a `date` or just a number?

Comment: return $this->hasMany(Saving::class,'member_id','id')->where('month',$value); you can chain where clauses to relation methods

Comment: it is just enum value @nakov

Comment: @AhmedAboud can you complete it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum is a wrong column for month my friend, unless you don't care for the year. Because this way you will just be able to store savings for each month, but not for each year separately.

Your relationship is set correctly, so you can then make a check like this:

```
// considering you have the specific member selected
$member = Member::find('ID_OF_THE_MEMBER');
if($member->savings()->where('month', APRIL)->exists())
{
    return 'Savings for this month are already added.';
}
```

Comment: add this code while inserting a saving? in savingController?

Comment: yes, before you save, this will prevent unless it meets the condition.

Comment: should i really use 'April' or $value ?? anyway it gives error :: $member is undefined.

Comment: You should use a `$value` that represents the month in your database as it is stored.
I showed you more/less pseudcode on how you can solve this my friend, didn't gave you exact solution that you can just copy-paste and it will work, thats why I left a comment in my code. When you are adding a new saving for a given member, do you have his ID? If you do, then you will need to get the same member and check if it exists. I will edit my answer now.

Comment: yes i did get it. i was just not sure how do i access member although i had the id

Comment: I saw your edit, but that won't work. You need to pass an id, not the column name. You need for example, `Member::find(1)`

Comment: shouldn't i send a variable ? now *$value* is not recognized. i haven't done this before. thanks for being patient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192548/discussion-between-nakov-and-prithvi-tuladhar).